# Service Fabric Reverse Proxy - Request Cancelation not working

Tags: reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I have experienced unexpected behavior from Service Fabric Reverse Proxy.

When I abort a long-running request the proxy request to the Service Fabric Service is not being aborted and the whole request is executed.

If we make requests directly to the service, requests are canceled as expected.

*An uninterrupted run of the long request - directly to the service*
[image: Uninterrupted run of the long request]

*An interrupted run of the long request - directly to the service*
[image]

Is there a setting that we need to enable so Service Fabric Reverse Proxy handles the requests as we expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik-extra-service-fabric) instead, which is a more mature product.
It comes with an active community and request termination support.

It also doesn't have the undesired side effect of exposing all SF services by default.

Comment: Traefik and Yarp are both good alternatives. I'm not looking for an alternative. I would expect request cancelation to be supported from the SF Reverse Proxy since it's the go-to communication for microservices with HTTP endpoints in SF. 
The side effect you mentioned is only a problem if you are exposing the reverse proxy, which isn't really recommended.